# Maven not pulling dependency from correct repository

Tags: maven, nexus, dependency-management

I have 3 repositories setup in our Nexus Repository manager

```
COMPANY_maven-proxy -> proxies https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/
COMPANY_maven-redhat-proxy -> proxies https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/
3rd-Party-Tools -> our companies homegrown 3rdParty dependencies
```

When I run the mvn install command it pulls everything I'm looking for from each of these repositories (the dependency itself and the transitive dependencies). All except for one!

```
org.jboss.seam.integration:jboss-seam-int-jbossas:pom:7.0.0.GA
```

This dependency lives in the Redhat maven repository:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.jboss.seam.integration</groupId>
   <artifactId>jboss-seam-int-jbossas</artifactId>
   <version>7.0.0.GA</version>
   <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

For whatever reason, this one dependency is looking under the COMPANY_maven-proxy repository instead of the COMPANY_maven-redhat-proxy repository.

Here's what I have for my settings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings>
    <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <!--This sends everything to COMPANY_maven-proxy that isn't in COMPANY_maven-redhat-proxy -->
      <id>COMPANY_maven-proxy</id>
      <url>http://FQDN:8081/nexus/repository/COMPANY_maven-proxy/</url>
      <mirrorOf>*,!COMPANY_maven-redhat-proxy</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
    <mirror>
      <!-- This sends everything to COMPANY_maven-redhat-proxy that isn't in COMPANY_maven-proxy -->
      <id>COMPANY_maven-redhat-proxy</id>
      <url>http://FQDN:8081/nexus/repository/COMPANY_maven-redhat-proxy/</url>
      <mirrorOf>*,!COMPANY_maven-proxy</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
    <mirror>
      <!--This sends everything else to 3rd-Party-Tools -->
      <id>3rd-Party-Tools</id>
      <url>http://FQDN:8081/nexus/repository/3rd-Party-Tools/</url>
      <mirrorOf>!COMPANY_maven-proxy,!COMPANY_maven-redhat-proxy</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
</settings>
```

Here's the error I get:

```
Failed to collect dependencies at org.jboss.seam.integration:jboss-seam-int- 
jbossas:pom:7.0.0.GA: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.jboss.seam.integration:jboss- 
seam-int-jbossas:pom:7.0.0.GA: Could not find artifact org.jboss.seam.integration:jboss-seam- 
int:pom:7.0.0.GA in COMPANY_maven-proxy (http://FQDN:8081/nexus/repository/COMPANY_maven-proxy/) -> [Help 1]
```

I've tried multiple combination's within the `<mirrorOf>` tag but nothing has worked. I've even put this transitive depency in my pom under `<dependencies>` and/or `<dependencyManagement>`.

Any help on this would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The mirrors are for already existing repositories declared. In your settings.xml you do not have repositories listed, but the default Maven Central. Thus it makes sense to define just a mirror of Maven Central, redirecting to the company's Nexus repo. with a rare trick, one could register a mirror for any external repos, for example:

```
    <mirror>
      <id>public</id>
      <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
      <name>Let the default Maven Central repository is resolved in the local Nexus' public repository</name>
      <url>http://FQDN:8081/nexus/repository/COMPANY_maven-proxy/</url>
    </mirror>
```

Any mirror from your example should be registered in the pom.xml as repositories.

Edited:

- removed the second ("other") mirror, as the example was adapted from a case where the repository manager to direct to runs at localhost.

Comment: I've updated my settings.xml to your example above and now it only pulls from ````COMPANY_maven-proxy```` and not from all the nexus repositories even though I have the three repositories specified in the pom.xml.

Comment: Just remove the "other" mirror. The example above works when used a local repository manager (my case), thus "external" means "other than localhost". In your case - any repository manager.

Comment: Ok, that solves that issue! However, I'm stilling getting the dependency error listed above ````Could not find artifact org.jboss.seam.integration:jboss-seam- 
int:pom:7.0.0.GA in COMPANY_maven-proxy (http://FQDN:8081/nexus/repository/COMPANY_maven-proxy/)````. This dependency is part of of the redhat maven repository ````https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/```` but it's trying to grab it from the ````https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/```` instead.

Comment: Please provide your pom.xml. From what you present so far I do not find any reference to https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/ repository. Do you have it described in the pom.xml? In the Nexus terms change the mirror to refer a group repository instead of the plain proxy (COMPANY_maven-proxy). Then add to the group this proxy repo and a proxy repo for https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/ (and any other repository external for the company) whenever you need it. This way, anything you read will be found in a proxy repository in that group.

Comment: Creating a maven group repository solved my issue. This allows me to add the proxied repositories as needed for transitive dependencies while only referring to the group. Excellent, thank you!